# How to use repository pattern with WCF for CRUD operations and avoid code duplication

Tags: .net, wcf, repository-pattern

I have a service that exposes some CRUD operations through a WCF interface.

**Service:**

```
bool SavePerson(Person obj)
{
  Repository<Person> currentRepo = new Repository<Person>();
  currentRepo.Save(obj);
}
bool SaveAddress(Address obj)
{
  Repository<Address> currentRepo = new Repository<Address>();
  currentRepo.Save(obj);
}
```

with the interface definitions for each

```
[OperationContract()]
bool SavePerson(Person obj);
[OperationContract()]
bool SaveAddress(Address obj);
```

I have a web client that consumes the methods.

**Web:**

```
SaveAddress(addr);
SavePerson(pers);
```

After browsing the site a bit, I know that generic methods don't work over WCF, so the Web can't do something like `SaveObject<Address>(addr); SaveObject<Person>(pers);`

My question is, is there a way to reduce the amount of code duplication? Ideally, I'd like to reduce the size of the WCF interface. Even if that's not doable though, would I at least be able to combine the method implementations on the service side?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

REST WCF services should help you. They will not implement exactly what you want but it is the only thing that can reduce amount interfaces and copy-paste.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd203052.aspx